# Supporting CSS 2 vs CSS 3 for modern & old browsers

Tags: css

Since many modern browsers support CSS3, I would like to use many CSS 3 features to use on my work but some older browsers still not support CSS3.
Should I separate those two css files separately? 
Or is there an effective way to handle both old and new browsers while having most of nice features of CSS 3.

Comment: What's wrong with putting them all in the same file? Stylesheets are not versioned in any way.

Comment: @BoltClock To take care of alternative effects or values for older browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

If you take a look at the very first lines of `index.html`, you'll see how to use various features of CSS depending on the browser, *all within the same CSS file*. The idea was originally explained [here](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).

In very short, the trick is to conditionnally define which CSS classes apply to `body` depending on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support many CSS3 features in IE6-9, [**you should use PIE**](http://css3pie.com/).